# angular service between controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services, angular-controller

I have a service which is empty on load:

```
app.factory("bookmark",function(){
    var bookmark = {};
    return bookmark;
});
```

I have controller A which sets the value of service and redirects to second controller where I try to access the service value which is empty.

Controller A:

```
app.controller('bookmarksController', function($scope, localStorageService, bookmark) {
  // localStorageService.clearAll();

  $scope.bookmarks = localStorageService.keys();
  $scope.setBookmarkServ = function (key){
    console.log('bookmark service set');

    bookmark = key;
    console.log(bookmark);

  }

  $scope.go2bookmark = function (key){

    console.log('go2bookmark called');

    var obj = localStorageService.get(key);
    return obj.link;
  }
});
```

Template A:

```
   <script type="text/ng-template" id="bookmarks">
    <div ng-controller="bookmarksController">
      <hr style="clear:both;opacity:0;" />
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <h1>Bookmarks</h1>
        <div ng-repeat="mark in bookmarks" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
             <a ng-click="setBookmarkServ(mark)" ng-init="theLink = go2bookmark(mark)" href="#{{theLink}}" class="thumbnail alert-info" style="height:150px;">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>{{ mark }}</h3>
                {{theLink}}
              </div>
             </a>
        </div>
     </div>  
    </script>
```

Controller B where service is {} empty:

```
app.controller('baselistController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$route', '$http', 'customview', '$location', '$uibModal', '$cacheFactory', '$templateCache', 'columnselector', '$interval', '$rootScope', 'globalVarService', '$window', '$controller', '$timeout', 'localStorageService', 'bookmark',

  function ($scope, $routeParams, $route, $http, customview, $location, $uibModal, $cacheFactory, $templateCache, columnselector,  $interval, $rootScope, globalVarService, $window, $controller, $timeout, localStorageService, bookmark) {

    //set value doesn't perist
    console.log(bookmark);
    ...
    ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
app.factory("bookmark",function(){
    var _bookmark = {};
    var setBookMark = function(key){
        _bookmark = key;
    }

    var getBookMark = function(){
        return _bookmark;
    }
    return {
        GetBookMark = getBookMark,
        SetBookMark = setBookMark 
    };
});
```

Now you can use this service to set and get bookmarks,

In controller A,

```
app.controller('bookmarksController', function($scope, localStorageService, bookmark) {
      bookmark.SetBookMark(localStorageService.keys(););
}
```

And get bookmark in Controller B,

```
app.controller('baselistController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$route', '$http', 'customview', '$location', '$uibModal', '$cacheFactory', '$templateCache', 'columnselector', '$interval', '$rootScope', 'globalVarService', '$window', '$controller', '$timeout', 'localStorageService', 'bookmark',
  function ($scope, $routeParams, $route, $http, customview, $location, $uibModal, $cacheFactory, $templateCache, columnselector,  $interval, $rootScope, globalVarService, $window, $controller, $timeout, localStorageService, bookmark) {

    console.log(bookmark.GetBookMark());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

@Abhilash gives the solution, let me explain the reason.

You need to understand the difference between `passed by reference` and `passed by value`: [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value).

You defined a service `bookmark`, actually it is like:

[image]

You injected the service `bookmark` to your controller. In this case, `bookmark` is a reference. When you are doing `bookmark = key;`, you lost the reference to the real object in the memory:

[image]

That is why your service cannot be shared between controllers. Because your modification does not actually make affect.

Solution: see @Abhilash's answer.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of

```
 $scope.bookmarks = localStorageService.keys();
```

save the bookmarks in

```
 $rootScope.bookmarks = localStorageService.keys();
```

so they will be shared across the app.

Comment: bookmark service is ! = $scope.bookmarks...... $scope will not persist route changes(as far as my understanding goes) i need  the use of service/factory...

Comment: Each time you call bookmark service it creates a new bookmark var, you can try like this:
    if (!bookmark){
        bookmark = {};
    }
    return bookmark;

Comment: It's a bad practice using $rootScope.